# How can I quickly mutate the weights of a tensorflow/keras neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

I've trained a game-playing neural network through supervised learning using tensorflow and keras and now want to have it play itself to improve. My strategy at the moment is to clone the model, apply some mutations and have it play itself with the winner "staying on".

The problem is mutating the network takes ages. It has 84'000'000 trainable weights and it takes me about 7 seconds to mutate them.

```
def gen_mutant(parent_model, mutation_rate):
    new_weights = parent_model.get_weights()
    for weight_array in new_weights:
        num_weights = weight_array.size
        num_weights_modified = np.random.binomial(num_weights, mutation_rate)
        for i in range(num_weights_modified):
            modify_weights(weight_array)
    mutant = tf.keras.models.clone_model(parent_model)
    mutant.set_weights(new_weights)
    return mutant

def modify_weights(weight_val):
    if np.isscalar(weight_val):
        np.random.normal(weight_val, abs(weight_val / 2))
    else:
        array_n = random.randint(0, len(weight_val)-1)
        modify_weights(weight_val[array_n])
```

Is there anything I can do to speed this process along? The structure of `parent_model.get_weights()` is a list of 6 numpy arrays (each of different shapes) which is why I've used the awkward recursive function.

(Bonus questions)
Is there a better way to train an existing keras/tf neural network through self play? From what I've read, it seem self-play doesn't really fit with their intended use.

Comment: is it something which tries to emulate GAN's ? (Generative Adversial Networks)

Comment: No trying to train a network to play a game using supervised learning but this only gets it so far, so I'm trying to incorporate some self-play to iron out some of its flaws.

Comment: understanding it in plain terms, what will be your input and output when you train ? when you say have it play itself ? you predict with a model and based on the loss you update the weights of the other model ? did i get it correctly ?

Comment: Input: game state
Output: probability score for each move (action)

So, initially I feed it pairs of game states and moves made so it learns to play certain moves given certain game states.
Then, in the self play, I mutate one copy of the model, have it play itself with the game_state -> move policy it learned in the supervised learning phase and pick the network which wins the game.

Comment: Will it be helpful if you write a custom callback (like CheckPoints which you use to save weights) & loss function, which gets called, after every epoch and does your mutation operation?

Comment: would that make the mutation any faster?

Comment: but you get access to the weights, at individual layers during the training itself and can write a mutation logic to probabilistically assign for different layers. I am not sure it would decrease the time, but I feel it would provide a clear picture of how the mutants are performing.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, might give it a shot! Thanks!